# How exactly does the "Honor Period" work?

Tags: paypal

PayPal describes a "Honor Period" that lasts for 3 days after you authorize or reauthorize a payment, up until 29 days after the first authorization. The docs don't really go into very much detail about this honor period though, just that you *should* capture within it and that you can restart an expired honor period by reauthorizing.

I have 3 main questions:

- When does the honor period start/end exactly? Is it an exact 72 hour window, to the second, from when you auth/reauth? Does it roll over at midnight or something instead? If so, what timezone?
- What is the preferred/recommended way to determine if the honor period for an authorization has expired or else determine the expiration time in the first place? Authorizations have a `expiration_time` field which marks the end of the 29 day window that an authorization is valid for. Is there a similar explicit time field for the honor period? Is it simply based on the `update_time` field on the latest auth/reauth?
- Is there a way to reauthorize before the previous authorization expires? Or more specifically, is there some way to ensure that the payment is always in an honor period, and that there is zero risk of some issue occurring because their funds weren't being held for a short amount of time before we reauthorized them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The honor period begins the moment a transaction is created and generally lasts 3 days. During this time, captures will generally succeed. During this time, the amount is generally reserved on the customer's funding source, which may be a credit or debit card, meaning they cannot spend it on other things.  The exact behavior may vary depending on the funding source and the country due to different implementations and local regulations.  The exact time at which an unused authorization "clears" from the customer's funding source and is no longer visible on their statement can also vary, and might take 10 days to no longer show up in some cases.

The rest of the PayPal authorization valid period -- a "post-honor" period, for lack of a better term -- begins on about day 4 and lasts until the end of day 29. During this time a capture attempt can still be made, and will succeed if money is available from the funding instrument. Such a later capture is roughly equivalent to the buyer themselves attempting a new transaction that is of type immediate capture, in the sense that they will succeed or fail for the same reasons.

Reauthorizations to get a new 3 day honor period (but which do NOT restart the 29-day authorization valid period) are almost always pointless. From day 4 to 29 just do a capture when you are ready, and forget you ever heard of the concept of reauthorization.

Comment: Interesting. This is kind of the feeling that I've had, that "if the capture would fail the reauth is just gonna fail anyways". I'll make sure to pass this up. Makes my life a bit easier, thanks!